# Regex list comparison Python

Tags: python, arraylist

How to compare two lists in python based on pattern from a list?

**Case 1:**

List_1 = ['aaa_123.csv','bbb_456.csv','ccc_789.csv','aaa_321.csv']

List_2 = ['aaa*.csv','bbb*.csv', 'ccc*.csv']

**Expected output:** All the elements in List_2 have matching pattern in List_1.

**Case 2:**

List_1 = ['aaa_123.csv','bbb_456.csv','aaa_321.csv']

List_2 = ['aaa*.csv','bbb*.csv', 'ccc*.csv','ddd*.csv']

**Expected output:** List_2 pattern is not fully matching with list_1. Match for the elements 'ccc*csv' & 'ddd.csv' is not found.

Comment: You tell us: [what code did you write so far](/help/how-to-ask)? Because if you didn't even spend enough time on websearches to _start_ trying things, it's way too early to ask on Stackoverflow.

Comment: Hi thanks for your response. I did tried few options, however I am unable to get the expected results.

Comment: Whether you get what you wanted doesn't matter so much as showing people _what_ you tried, so they don't end up going "try X" and then you going "I already did". [Tell people what you tried](/help/how-to-ask), so they don't have to ask.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Python `fnmatch` module was designed for exactly this purpose.  Remember, what you have there are not regular expressions.  They are shell "glob" patterns, and `fnmatch` is like `glob` for strings:

```
import fnmatch

def check( names, patterns ):
    return all(fnmatch.filter(names,p) for p in patterns)

List_1 = ['aaa_123.csv','bbb_456.csv','ccc_789.csv','aaa_321.csv']
List_2 = ['aaa*.csv','bbb*.csv', 'ccc*.csv']
print(check(List_1,List_2))

List_1 = ['aaa_123.csv','bbb_456.csv','aaa_321.csv']
List_2 = ['aaa*.csv','bbb*.csv', 'ccc*.csv','ddd*.csv']
print(check(List_1,List_2))
```

Output:

```
True
False
```

Answer (score 0):

The following code should also work.

```
import re

def compare_lists(list1, list2):
    return all(
        any(re.match(pattern.replace("*", ".*"), element) for element in list1)
        for pattern in list2
    )
```

We use a nested list comprehension to check if any pattern from list2 matches any element from list1 using regular expressions. We replace * with .* in each pattern using the replace() method, and check whether the resulting regular expression matches any element in list1 using another generator expression and the any() function. We then use the all() function to check whether all patterns in list2 match at least one element in list1.

Here's how you can use this function with the two test cases you provided:

```
# Test the function with the provided examples
list1 = ["aaa_123.csv", "bbb_456.csv", "ccc_789.csv", "aaa_321.csv"]
list2 = ["aaa*.csv", "bbb*.csv", "ccc*.csv"]
result = compare_lists(list1, list2)
print(result)  # should print True

list1 = ["aaa_123.csv", "bbb_456.csv", "aaa_321.csv"]
list2 = ["aaa*.csv", "bbb*.csv", "ccc*.csv", "ddd*.csv"]
result = compare_lists(list1, list2)
print(result)  # should print Fals
```

**Results:**

```
True
False
```

I hope this helps you achieve what you're looking for!